# How to block all hacking?

Tags: php, apache2, mysql, linux, ftp

The title explains most of my question. The OS is linux (Lubuntu). The servers are Apache2 (PHP5), MySQL 5.6 and FTP (Samba).

Comment: That's easy... don't plug it in to the internet!

Comment: in other words: if there is a door – somebody will be able to open it.

Comment: @w3d is right. Hacking can only be mitigated but can be mitigated to a largely effective degree.

Comment: Samba is FTP? Hmm, explain that one. Anyway, not a good idea to expose SMB to the internet in the first place. SCP/SFTP if you want file transfer.

Comment: You can't. There always new methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent hacking to an extent however, nothing is perfect and there are always flaws in any system. Asking a question with such little detail prevents a comprehensive insightful answer. 
It's advisable to read up and practice Linux and PHP security concepts. However it's impossible to make your website "hackproof", you can make it "hack-resistant" though. Secure the core, code your application securely and it might not be a bad idea to invest in a firewall on the network, server and web application layers.